# jquery autocomplete specific bold issue

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I've got autocomplete source with values like 'JOHN SMITH', 'LIN SMITH', JOHN STAINIGER';

I want to enable user if he writes **SMITH** in the output to see also the suggestions ''JOHN SMITH', 'LIN SMITH' and when he writes **SMITH J** he should see only JOHN SMITH.

So I've made autocomplete to search both ways - JOHN S and SMITH J will both give me JOHN SMITH

The problem is with bold- I've made this function which makes the req. term item bold no matter where it finds the req. erm in the string.

But if I write SMITH J and that's my req. term then it will bold nothing because it cannot find this req. term in JOHN SMITH. How can i change that?

How can i change that
    function monkeyPatchAutocomplete() {

```
   $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            var highlighted = item.label.split(this.term).join('<strong>' + this.term +  '</strong>');
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>" + highlighted + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
}
}
```